# Row-Level Data Security in API Architecture

Tags: mysql, database, architecture

I have the following tables:

- User (id, username, etc) - primary is id
- Team (id, companyId, teamName, etc) - primary is id
- Company (id, name) - primary is id
- TeamUser (many teams to many users) - id, teamId, userId
- CompanyTeam (one company to many
  teams) - id, companyId, teamId
- CompanyUser (companyId, userId)

I have created a web application that is getting increasingly complex with objects that are owned by users, teams, or companies, and that can be "shared" individually with any of the above.

Say for example you have a Document object. A user can create a document object that they own personally, a team member can create a document at the team level for sharing with the whole team, and a company administrator can create a document that is shared with the whole company. Any of those can be shared with a given user, team, or company individually as well.

Tables are:

- Document (id,name,etc) - primary is id
- DocumentOwner (id, documentId, userId, teamId, companyId, etc.) - the history is retained in changes to ownership, so we're selecting max id from this table for a given documentId to determine the current owner.

My queries for the objects are all having to check if the user is part of the team that owns the object, or part of the company that owns the object, or the user owns the object, or the user has had the object shared with them. As the sharing gets more complex the queries do not seem scalable and I think the issue may be with the database structure that is requiring a lot of joins meshed with permissions, particularly for objects that are increasingly complex. Here's an example of getting a list of documents the user has access to:

```
SET @UserId = 123;

Select documentId
FROM Document
JOIN DocumentOwner ON
     DocumentOwner.UserId = @UserId
     OR DocumentOwner.TeamId in (select teamId from TeamUser where userId = @UserId)
     OR DocumentOwner.CompanyId in (select companyId from CompanyUser where id = @UserId)
```

So if I want to get a single document, a list of documents, filter lists etc, this whole chunk of code basically has to go in every time to see if the user should be able to access it.

To be clear, I am not looking for RBAC - the roles and permissions model is working fine for CRUD actions, I'm more concerned with database architecture and SQL structures for getting the data efficiently once it is saved in a "complex sharing" data structure.

Comment: please show table structure and sample data.

Comment: @dodzb added table structure and an example query.

Comment: to be honest, your database design is not scalable. It only stuck to few purposes. You must redesign your document handling structure. Keep it simple. Create a separate table that contains ID's and numbers only represents relationships for a document.

Comment: @dodzb that is all that is in the Document Owner table.